# Assigining class to an ID based on highest no. of subclasses - Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

So actually I have a dataframe with some `videoID` under which there is a chain of videos with subcategories and I want to assign the highest occurring class. So my dataframe looks like this,

```
videoId   postId   class

12234     788         1
12234     789         1
12234     790         3
12234     791         4
12234     792         1
12234     793         4
```

So I want a dataframe like this for every such videoId:

```
videoId   class
  12234      1
```

Since  highest occurring class is 1 (counting he subposts classes) under that `videoId`

Now suppose if I have a  tie between the classes say like this:

```
videoId   postId   class

1620      34          1
1620      35          1
1620      36          2
1620      37          2
```

I want it to be like this:

```
 videoId  class
 1620      1
 1620      2
```

So when, there is a tie between the subclasses I want all of them to appear for that `videoId`. I have tried several w ays, by doing `value_counts()`, `max()`, etc. but was not able to reach to the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply apply `mode` over groupby and reset index i.e

```
df.groupby('videoId')['class'].apply(pd.Series.mode).reset_index(level=0)

  videoId  class
0     1620      1
1     1620      2
```

Comment: totally forgot about the mode function, works like a charm. thanks

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is to use dense ranking:

```
df.groupby('videoId')['class'].value_counts()\
  .rank(method='dense',ascending=False)\
  .rename('ranking')\
  .reset_index()\
  .query('ranking == 1')
```

Output:

```
   videoId  class  ranking
0     1620      1      1.0
1     1620      2      1.0
```